# PHP DOM Parser Find First Child of Div With Specific Class and Search Each Elements

Tags: php, html, arrays, dom

As the title says Im trying to find the first child of an element with a specific class here is what I would like to do:

**Update:** I added the format. Also I figured how to get to the tbody. But at the end of the day what I am trying to do is check each element within tbody if they each equal to "--" or not. How would I achieve this then? Would I convert the DOM Object to a string? Whats an efficient way to do this.

**Update 2:** I found an elegant solution which I updated to my code. Still the question lingers: Whats the best way to check if there are integers? Do I just convert each element to a string and then do a strpos condition?

**Update 3:** Nevermind I figured it out.Included below is the solution. I had to go one step further into the table body to select the table rows and loop through them instead.

```html
foreach($html->find('div[class=compareSkillsOuter clear] section[class=playerStats] div[class=tiledBlueFrame] div[class=tableWrap] table[class=headerBgLeft] tbody tr') as $element){
    if($position = strrpos($element, '--');
    if($position !== false){
        echo "String found";
    }
    else{
        echo "String not found";
    }
}
```

Format:

```html
<div class="compareSkillsOuter clear">
    <section class="playerStats">
        <div class="tiledBlueFrame">
            <div class="tl corner"></div>
            <div class="tr corner"></div>
     <div class="bl corner"></div>
            <div class="br corner"></div>
            <div class="tableWrap">
                <table class="headerBgLeft">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="alignleft">Rank</th>
                            <th class="alignleft">Total XP</th>
                            <th class="alignleft">Level</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr >
                            <td class="alignleft"><a href="#">1,700,012</a></td>
                            <td class="alignleft"><a href="#">3,290</a></td>
                            <td class="playerWinLeft alignleft"><div class="relative"><a href="#">55</a></div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class=oddRow>
                            <td class="alignleft"><a href="#">--</a></td>
                            <td class="alignleft"><a href="#">--</a></td>
                            <td class="alignleft"><a href="#">--</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Best Solution:

```html
  $data = $html->find("table[class=headerBgLeft] tbody",0);
  $data1 = $data->find("tr td a");

  $statistics = Array();

  
  //echo $data1[1]->plaintext;

  foreach($data1 as $tr)
   {
    //store each
   echo "$tr 1<br>";
  }
```

Comment: Okey great, now I got a question for you. Do we *magically* know how your DOM structure looks like? What is the output, what is the *desired* output? Where is the red carpet?

Comment: @Xorifelse oh thank you for remind me. I have added it in the code. Also revised a description what Im trying to do. The tbody contains integer values. If it is null then they default to '--'. How would I check the tbody if each has an integer within it or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You want to find tr body than just use table and tbody element. find always return an array and your if statement is with semicolon.

```
$data= $html->find("table[class=headerBgLeft] tbody");
$data1=$data->find("td tr");
foreach($data1 as $ed)
 {
    if($ed->innertext=="--")
      echo "String is found";
    else
      echo "String is not found";
 }
```

If you only need to find that two dashes within tbody and their position is fixed means they always in second tr. You can use

```
  $data1=$data->find("td tr",1);
```

If it is not your problem. Or it does not work please comment. I have not tested it.

Comment: But what if there are two  <section class="playerStats"> with the sam structure. I simplified it. I havent tried it yet but I believe it will grab both of them, which is why I resorted to the other odd method in my post

Comment: That site html is alway changing its structure? The most important thing is what do you want. If you want to fetch data from (if there is more section element with that class you specified) both section code will same. If only from first section code will change. Please tell me what do you want actually?

Comment: @potion if you want to scrap data from first section than use `$data= $html->find("table[class=headerBgLeft] tbody",0);`

Comment: No the site structure is static. So theres two tables of the same class. That seems to work. How about selecting the second table?

Comment: @potion if you want to scrap data from second section than use `$data= $html->find("table[class=headerBgLeft] tbody",1);`

Comment: This worked nicely. How would I cycle through each element storing only the plain text? Like so   

`for($i = 0; i<=84; i++){
    $statistics[i] = $data1[i]->plaintext;
}`

Comment: First clear what you want, than I help you. Every time your question change

Comment: Count number of element in $data array, put that value on for loop condition. And your rest of code is fine